# Locking a mutex vs accessing disk

Tags: c++, multithreading

Which is *generally* more efficient between locking a mutex and doing disk reads in C++?

If it depends on the system I'm running, what's a good way to check this? Would doing 1 million locks vs 1 million disk reads work?

Comment: Not sure about the context of this question.  Given no contention, a mutex lock would be a kernel call and back agin.  An unbuffered disk read from a hard disk means user>kernel>driver>SATA>controller>movingMechanicalStuff/waitingForSector and back again, so lengthy.  Could you refine your question with more context?

Comment: @MartinJames: An uncontended mutex lock may not even involve a kernel call - in modern Linux, it just tests and sets a flag in userspace.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes, maybe on Linux or Windows, assuming the mutex not an interprocess lock.  It needs an OS call on my embedded systems, though. Anyway, I think that we can all agree that, all else being equal, the mutex lokc is going to be piles faster.  That's why I asked about context - it's a funny question..

Comment: @Martin, sorry the question didn't have enough context. Your reply was super helpful. +1

Comment: @blaze, no, not a phone screening question, but it actually makes a good one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, the mutex operations would be *far* faster than disk reads. That's because their intended purpose requires maximum speed. In fact, I would hazard to suggest that *any* memory operation is likely to be faster than a disk one.

Of course, there may be bizarre edge cases where the disk information is cached in memory and 
you read the same byte over and over but that's not really doing a disk read, is it?

If you *find* yourself with a desire to check this (and I would suggest it's not really necessary), simply code up a couple of programs, the first which locks and unlocks a mutex a million times, the second which reads a million different pieces of information off the disk.

Run them and compare them. If, by some bizarre factor, the disk reads come back faster, show us your code and we'll explain what you did wrong :-)

Answer (score 4):

Locking a mutex, by **far**. The RAM + CPU is **much** faster than even the fastest SSD.